# How to spread out satellites from planet using smartdiagram

Tags: smartdiagram

**Question:**

How can I push the satellites out so that they don't overlap?

**MWE/Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \smartdiagramset{
        bubble node font=\footnotesize,
        bubble center node color=red!15,
        planet font=\footnotesize, 
        % set color list={blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25},
        uniform color list=blue!60 for 8 items,
        border color=none,
        %planet text width=10cm,
        planet size=4.0cm, 
        satellite size=1.0cm, 
        }
    \tikzset{bubble node/.append style={draw=none}}
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
        Dante,
        Ultimo,
        Brooklyn II,
        IP Core,
        Broadway,
        HC,
        PCIe-R,
        AV,
        Adaptor\\Modules
        }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between the satellites and the center is stored in `distance center/other bubbles`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \smartdiagramset{
        bubble node font=\footnotesize,
        bubble center node color=red!15,
        planet font=\footnotesize, 
        % set color list={blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25},
        uniform color list=blue!60 for 8 items,
        border color=none,
        %planet text width=10cm,
        planet size=4.0cm, 
        satellite size=1.0cm, 
         distance center/other bubbles=1.4cm
        }
    \tikzset{bubble node/.append style={draw=none}}
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{
        Dante,
        Ultimo,
        Brooklyn II,
        IP Core,
        Broadway,
        HC,
        PCIe-R,
        AV,
        Adaptor\\Modules
        }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or a constellation diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \smartdiagramset{
        satellite font =\footnotesize,
        planet color=red!15,
        planet font=\footnotesize, 
        % set color list={blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25,blue!25},
        uniform color list=blue!60 for 8 items,
        border color=none,
        planet size=4.0cm, 
        distance planet-satellite=4cm
        }
    %\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={draw=none}}
    \smartdiagram[constellation diagram]{
        Dante,
        Ultimo,
        Brooklyn II,
        IP Core,
        Broadway,
        HC,
        PCIe-R,
        AV,
        Adaptor\\Modules
        }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and if I wanted each of the sattelites to be connected to the "planet" (Dante)? How would I do this?

Comment: @3kstc AFAIK bubble diagrams do not come with arrows. You may either hack it or use a `constellation diagram`.

Comment: or mindmap is good

Comment: You guys are LaTeX angels in disguise! Hope everyone's safe during the pandemic - and thank you for your help <3.